# Which PHP framework to choose for building a penny auction website and why?

Tags: php, frameworks

Since I have never used any PHP frameworks, I'd like you to suggest me some.

My main objective is writing a fully functional penny auction script, something similar to swoopo.com and bidhere.com.

While at it, please leave reasons why you think the particular framework is best suited for this job.

Comment: There is no best suited framework for that task. Frameworks aid some technicalities, but generally provide no features for specific site behaviours. You might want to look for a WebCMS and readymade module thingys.

Comment: What have you used before if you have not used frameworks?

Comment: This question's really subjective - as others have said, there's no real right answer here, and without knowing details of your implementation it's going to be tough to give you a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend reading this question when it comes to choosing a framework.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648/what-php-framework-would-you-choose-for-a-new-application-and-why

There is not a specific framework that is better for one site than another.  It depends more on how you want to implement the code.

However, I would recommend that you write your own small framework.  This is what I have done and it is very beneficial:

- Let's you be flexible with the code.
- Good for a resume
- Learn a lot while doing it
- Discover stuff that you had never known about
- Know how the site works from the ground up

From there you can copy your framework and use it on future websites.  Also, when doing freelance work you can advertise that you fully coded everything, which may equal more money.

When I was looking into frameworks I did not like how any of them displaying templates and went the route of making my own framework and definitely am happy that I chose to.  No longer do I have to worry about settings that I will never use.  (This should also result in some faster speeds, but am not completely sure about this.)

Comment: Don't be so quick to rush into building your own framework.  It will mean a HUGE learning curve for anyone else who joins your team.  And if you have to suddenly leave the project, it's even worse because you're the only one who understands the code.  Open-source frameworks have lots more eyeballs looking at the code, fixing bugs, adding extra features, and documenting the project.  Hardware is cheap compared to developer expertise.  Use more powerful machines if you have to, but definitely use open source frameworks wherever possible.

Answer (score 0):

Like mario said, there's nothing specifically suited for that task.

However, I've been developing in CakePHP for awhile and find it to be very easy to use and standards-based. And perhaps most importantly, there's a very active community of developers/users that can answer any questions, as well as a large database of plugins and other helpers.